# error messages in cipher code

Tags: python, string, key, translate, encryption

I am doing a cipher in python right now and I need some help on how call another external function inside another function

here's the external function...which is working 100% correctly so far!

```
def buildCoder(shift):
    import string
    import random
    from itertools import chain, islice
    from string import ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase   
    def _helper(letters):
        return dict(zip(letters, chain(islice(letters, shift, None), letters)))
    d = _helper(ascii_uppercase)
    d.update(_helper(ascii_lowercase))
    return d
```

and here's the new function:

```
def applyCoder(text, coder):
    buildCoder(int(n))
    coder = buildCoder(int(n))
    newtext = string.translate(text, buildCoder(int(n)))
    return newtext
```

---

there's something wrong with the code - here are a few test cases below 
Test Cases

```
>>> applyCoder("Hello, world!", buildCoder(3))
'Khoor, zruog!'
>>> applyCoder("Khoor, zruog!", buildCoder(23))
'Hello, world!'
```

the above results should pop up when tests like that are done...

however I'm getting the following error message whenever I call the above function `applyCoder("string",buildCoder(n))` it's saying n is not defined but if I call the function - say for example `applyCoder("drink milk love life",buildCoder(5))` it gives the following output:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
     applyCoder("drink milk love life", buildCoder(5))
  File "C:\ProblemSet5\ProblemSet5\ps5_encryption.py", line 143, in applyCoder
    buildCoder(int(n))
NameError: global name 'n' is not defined
```

so how would I end up fixing this function at all - `def applyCoder(text, coder):`?

Comment: Please try to format your post without so much bold text... And add language tag (i.e. instead of "key")

Comment: Also please give a title that communicates something about the question.

Comment: i formatted it...and  changed the title

Comment: anyone not able to help me out in calling this function?

the def applyCoder(text, coder): needs help!

pls help out asap...thnx a million!

Comment: yoo hoo...anyone home?

Comment: is every1 sleeping now? is this question so difficult to answer?

Comment: Added python tag, that should help to lead people here who actually know python and can possibly answer the question.

Comment: I see you haven't accepted any answers to any of your questions. Do [accept and/or upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168143/206447) answers you found helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The n refers to the global n.

you wrote something like this in your pythonshell:

```
n = ...

def applyCoder(text, coder):
    buildCoder(int(n))
    coder = buildCoder(int(n))
    newtext = string.translate(text, buildCoder(int(n)))
    return newtext

n = ... # or this
```

But this should look like this:

```
def applyCoder(text, coder):
    newtext = string.translate(text, coder)
    return newtext
```

Does it help?